# Submit jQuery ajax Form with multi buttons and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

here is my problem:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
<form id="roomform" action="room.php" method="POST">
<button name="room" value="Room01">IMG01</button>
<button name="room" value="Room02">IMG02</button>
<button name="room" value="Room03">IMG03</button>
<button name="room" value="Room04">IMG04</button>
<button name="room" value="Room05">IMG05</button>
<button name="room" value="Room06">IMG06</button>
<button name="room" value="Room07">IMG07</button>
<button name="room" value="Room08">IMG08</button>
<button name="room" value="Room09">IMG09</button>
<button name="room" value="Room10">IMG10</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var frm = $('#roomform');
    frm.submit(function (ev) {
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert('ok');
            }
        });

        ev.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP using $_POST['room'] to get the room name Room01-Room10(Room100 maybe?) and doing something special.
It works good.
Now I need to do this using Ajax. Above code seems ok, but I cannot get any data(Room01-Room10) from it.

then I found this:

```
<form action="/vote/" method="post" class="vote_form">
    <input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="10" />
    <input type="image" src="vote_down.png" class="vote_down" name="submit" value="down" />
    <input type="image" src="vote_up.png" class="vote_up" name="submit" value="up" />
</form>

$(".vote_form").submit(function() { return false; });
$(".vote_up, .vote_down").click(function(event) {
    $form = $(this).parent("form");
    $.post($form.attr("action"), $form.serialize() + "&submit="+ $(this).attr("value"), function(data) {
        // do something with response (data)
    });
});
```

but it seems not suitable to my case, my all buttons with same name="room" for $_POST['room'] and no class.
and this not works:

```
$(function() {
  $('input[name=room]').click(function(){
    var _data= $('#roomform').serialize() + '&room=' + $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "room.php?",
      data:_data,
      success: function(html){
         $('div#1').html(html);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: `serialize()` doesn't return buttons, because how is it supposed to know which button to put in the parameters?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/serialize/   `Note: Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. No submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a button.`

Comment: I think the code at the end of the question should work. Have you looked at what is being sent in the Network tab of developer tools/firebug?

Comment: after modify the "input" to "button", it works. :) thanks redelschaap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your (last) code is not sending AJAX requests because you attached the handler to the wrong input selector. Your buttons are `button` elements, not `input` elements. This should work:

```
$('button[name=room]').click(function() { ...
```

Edit:

Your first code isn't working because your buttons are just buttons. You have to add the `type` attribute to let your form know you're pressing a submit button: `<button type="submit"...>`

Comment: thanks, button[name=room] works! I tried type="submit" before, it not works.

Answer (score 0):

The serialize() method does not collect the data from a button element. Take a look to the documentation on this link: https://api.jquery.com/serialize/.  In your code I would assume that your data object is empty.

Also if you post several form controls (serialized) , they should have different name attributes.